# Python: why is operator.__mul__ much faster than int.__mul__

Tags: python

I'm playing with Python and decided to code a factorial function in two slightly different ways:

```
import operator
def fact1(n):
    return reduce(operator.__mul__,xrange(1,n+1))
```

and

```
def fact2(n):
    return reduce(int.__mul__,xrange(1,n+1))
```

I was quite surprised when timing them:

```
timeit fact1(10)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 933 ns per loop
timeit fact2(10)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.46 us per loop
```

`operator.__mul__` seems to be twice faster than `int.__mul__` (on top of not breaking down when the factorial values gets so large Python converts it from `int` to `long`)

I'm quite new to Python and so I don't know how these functions differ. Is there an underlying reason for the difference in performance?